# Поиск подмассива в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы

## Описание

Вопрос такой "общий".
Есть массив какой-нибудь:

```cs
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

ну и чтобы проверить существование какого нибудь подмассива в нем я написал:

```cs
bool ContainSubarray<T>(T[] array, T[] subarray) where T : IComparable<T> {
    var contains = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - subarray.Length + 1; i++) {
        var match = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < subarray.Length; j++) {
            if (array[i + j].CompareTo(subarray[j]) != 0) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match) {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return contains;
}
```

```cs
int[] subarray = { 3, 4, 5 };
var result = ContainSubarray(array, subarray); // true
```

## Вопрос

Как можно это реализовать для *прямоугольных*, *многомерных* массивов?
Я догадываюсь что через цикл, только каждый раз взять соответственную строку подмассива и. т. п., но я столкнулся с проблемами - с взятием строки например двумерного массива, с реализацией цикла, с оптимизацией.
**Можете привести пример хотя бы для двумерного массива и описать производительный алгоритм для n-мерного?**

Comment: а как в вашем двумерном массиве могут располагаться подмассивы? Столбцом/строкой/по диагонали?
Если строкой, берите каждый k элемент каждого столбца
Если столбцом, то в каждом столбце ищите подмассив
Если по диагонали, то смотрите в каждом столбце элементы с индесами по строке k, k+1,k+2

Comment: @SpaceResearcher и столбцом, и строкой, и по диагонали, и по другим методам. Для примера берите фигуры в тетрис, если считать что доска тетрис это наш двумерный массив.

Comment: С неуправляемыми типами (числа) можно очень быстрый код написать, для `IComparable` такие фокусы не прокатят, только поэлементное сравнение. А вообще N-мерные массивы нигде не используются, только в обучающих задачах в основном. На практике они неудобные. Не совсем ясна цель, для которой нужен данный код. Ну хотя-бы вот пример для 2D https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1453733/373567

Comment: @aepot посмотрел ответ, спасибо. И этим помогли нехило так. Неуправляемые типы в основном нужны для сравнения базовых типов, но неизвестно это будет int, bool, string или ещё что-то.